# Perl скрипт и загрузка страницы

Tags: html, perl

Я хотел бы спросить, как можно написать код веб странички на html чтобы одновременно с загрузкой страницы запускался скрипт?

Comment: Скрипт на стороне клиента или сервера? Под IIS и IE это (perlasp на сервере и perlscript на клиенте) можно было делать ещё в прошлом тысячелетии. Ну перловые cgi-скрипты -- вообще классика жанра 90х.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например сделать вызов скрипта загрузкой картинки `<img src="http://domain.ru/scrip.pl"/>` или как вызов яваскрипта `<script src="http://domain.ru/scrip.pl"></script>`, или на худой конец как iframe <`iframe src="http://domain.ru/scrip.pl"></iframe>`, поля чтобы сделать iframe невидимым - гуглите, я не помню.

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от того, что этот скрипт должен делать:
Если он выводит некоторую текстовую информацию внутрь страницы, то можно использовать SSI ([узнать больше про SSI в apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html)), например:

```
<!--#include virtual="/cgi-bin/script.cgi" -->
```

Ограничение SSI - только внутри одного сервера.

Если это какой-то внешний ресурс, например картинка, то в HTML:

```
<img src="/cgi-bin/script.cgi" />
```

Но в этом случае этот ресурс бкдет запрошен только "нормальным" броузером который загружает картинки и роботы (google, yandex) этот скрипт дергать не будут.